# Как вставить рисунок в JTable java

Tags: jtable, изображения, java

Здравствуйте, прошу Вас помочь мне в одном моменте с `java swing JTable`! Уже неделю я бьюсь с проблемой: по нажатию кнопки в имеющуюся таблицу вставить рисунок (`ImageIcon`). На форумах и в туториалах адекватной инфы не нашел.

Прошу, помогите в решении проблемки. Вот код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class render extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
           ImageIcon Icon;
       public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
          JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focus,
          int row, int col) {
          JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focus, row, col);
               Icon=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("love.gif"));
           l.setIcon(Icon);
           return l;
         }
    }

public class TableAppl {
    JTable table;
    ImageIcon myIcon;

    TableAppl() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table app");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(500,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myIcon = new ImageIcon("love.jpg");
        Object[][] data = {{"1","2","3","4"},
                {"1","2","3","4"},
                {"1","2","3","4"},
                {"1","2","3","4"},
                {"1","2","3","4"},
        };
        String[] head = {"111","222","333","444"};
        table = new JTable(data, head);
        JScrollPane stab = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(800,80));

        render myrend = new render();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class, myrend);

        JButton but = new JButton("Change pic");
        but.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                table.setValueAt(myIcon, 2, 1);
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(stab);
        frame.getContentPane().add(but);
        frame.setSize(850,175);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new TableAppl();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

С Уважением, Роман

Answer (score 1):

Это не оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941372/how-to-insert-image-into-jtable-cell